# Include earlier captured group in regex itself

Tags: javascript, regex, vbscript

I want this regex to work.
after finding first captured group, is it possible to refer it to same regex string.

```
(EP \d{5,7})(?:.*[\r\n]+){52}.*$1
```

I am currently using notepad++ to find the same in this way which works.

```
(EP \d{5,7})(?:.*[\r\n]+){52}.*\1
```

Is this possible in javascrip or vbscript regexp.
I tried using windows vbscript, Jscript and https://regex101.com/#javascript but seems like I am making some mistake.

Comment: `\1` should work, can you add the input string

Comment: It's very large. If I put that here people will kill me by down voting as they are already started doing. You can see from regex it self that it is 52 lines long. Do you have any Idea how to share such long string in this forum.

Comment: Try to put it in https://regex101.com/#javascript by dividing the string to minimal to reproduce the issue

Comment: My actual regex is itself half page long. I have truncated the regex where the problem is coming. Up to `(EP \d{5,7})(?:.*[\r\n]+){52}.*` works perfectly but as soon as I put $1. It stops.

Comment: @Rahul: For long strings make use of [pastebin](https://www.pastebin.com) and share the link.

Comment: Cyberoam problem. Thanks for suggestion. will be useful for questioning while at home or on mobile. I got the answer thought. as I was having large regex string, I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript a backreference is also denoted by a backslash

```
(test)\1
```

Comment: OP is aware of that.

Comment: Apology for disappointing you sir, but I wasn't. I tried many languages method to find and replace using regex (python, perl, ruby). so got confused as replacement was done using $1, I thought naturally same should be used for back referencing but was not working for one or the more reason. Also made some mistakes in overall regex. It's working fine now.